# What is a Mars 5-sol orbit?

Tags: mars, orbit

I need to calculate the delta-v for descent from 5-sol orbit to the surface of Mars and then ascent back to 5-sol orbit from the surface of Mars.  What is a "5-sol orbit?"

Comment: Hint: Sol = Mars day

Comment: By "5 sol orbit" do you mean "A circular orbit over Mars with a period 5 sols long?"

Comment: @notovny This seems like already an answer – the OP obviously doesn't know what is meant, they just got this task from someone else.

Comment: "What is a '5-sol orbit'?" is pretty darn clear, and the prompt, clear and comprehensive answer makes that pretty obvious. The question *does not ask* anything that requires the eccentricity. Yes they may need that information. but but notovny's question does not need to be addressed. The OP means simply 
 a "5-sol oribt", no more. The close votes for "needs clarity" are therefore inappropriate. **voting to leave open!**

Comment: and now **voting to re-open!** because no need to block answers (which is what closing does)

Comment: @uhoh I think the disconnect between the title of “what is X?” and the question body taking about Delta-V and such is why it’s unclear. If it was reformulated to ask more about what a “5-sol orbit” is it would be less unclear (maybe even the context of where they got the term?)

Comment: @fyrepenguin I read it (and edited it, admittedly) then answered it as "I need to Do A with B.  What is B?"  OP has commented on my answer without objecting to it.  That doesn't prove my interpretation is the only correct one, but it's suggestive.  Why would the context of where OP got the term be clarifying?

Comment: @ErinAnne as-is, it feels somewhat like someone asking “I need to know how to set up a tent. What is a tent?”  Basically, if you don’t know what it is, why or how do you know that’s what you want to do? I did read the original form of the question and think that my comment still applies

Comment: I don’t think this is an inherently bad question, though it’s kind of asking two questions in one, especially in light of the new question the OP asked. As-is they’re now asking about the deta-v calculations in two places, it might be clearer to disambiguate the two questions

Comment: @fyrepenguin my response is getting a little long so [I've created a chat room to continue discussion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144938/discussion-about-close-votes-on-what-is-a-mars-5-sol-orbit) if that's ok

Answer (score 16):

**tl;dr** it's an orbit around Mars with a period 5-sols long, but in the literature they're typically parking orbits so don't assume they're circular.  Check the last two paragraphs for a potential trap.

I googled around a bit to check if this was being used in a way differently than all of us have leapt to (i.e. "5-sol is a direct statement of the period of the orbit"), but [A Polar Orbit for the Mars Global Network Mission](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19910005048/downloads/19910005048.pdf) gives a 1/5 sol orbit with a 275km periapsis altitude.  A bit of Kepler's law shows that this is a reasonable periapsis altitude for a 0.2-sol orbital period (and it's stated to be "the most-elliptical site-synchronous orbit with the required characteristics", so the slightly higher semimajor axis value I found just means the apoapsis can be higher).

I've seen 5-sol orbits referenced as parking orbits in e.g. [Optimizing Parking Orbits for Roundtrip Mars Missions](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20170008844/downloads/20170008844.pdf); in that paper the periapsis is 250km (page 6).  So it seems at least circularity is not guaranteed.

A subtlety that might be present here: a [Mars sol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_sol) is supposed to be a solar day, but if these orbits are intended to be site-synchronous I think the Mars sidereal day would be the period you'd want to multiply.  Solar and sidereal day lengths are slightly different.

Because of that timing subtlety, but also just as a good rule of thumb, maybe check with whoever you have to work those delta-Vs out for that you've defined the "5-sol orbit" the same way.

Comment: Especially because parking orbits shouldn't really be that high.

Comment: Sorry, the question was closed by someone. I have updated this question and looking forward to re-opening.

Comment: @PrashantModak what update did you make?  [Edit 3](https://space.stackexchange.com/revisions/63203/3) seems to be empty, which I didn't even know was possible.